# Publish SSRS by Octopus

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, octopus-deploy

I'm building the set up to deploy my SSRS reports through Octopus Deploy, I found out one [Octopus Library](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/#!/step-template/actiontemplate-deploy-ssrs-reports-from-a-package) and I'm working on it, but I've had some issues:

1º ---- Message error: (The path is alright, but it keeps with the same warning)
WARNING: Unable to find datasource SalesDrivers in /Sales Drivers/Data Sources

2º ---- The method doesn't exist
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3er_ReportService2005_asmx_wsdl.ReportingService2005] doesn't contain a method named 'LoadReportDefinition'.

The powershell function from the template\library that is throwing the error can been seen below:

```
#region Update-ReportParamters()
Function Update-ReportParameters($ReportFile)
{
    # declare local variables
    $ReportParameters = @();

    # necessary so that when attempting to use the report execution service, it doesn't puke on you when it can't find the data source
    $ReportData = (Remove-SharedReferences -ReportFile $ReportFile)

    # get just the report name
    $ReportName = $ReportFile.SubString($ReportFile.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
    $ReportName = $ReportName.SubString(0, $ReportName.IndexOf("."))

    # create warnings object
    $ReportExecutionWarnings = $null

    # load the report definition
    Write-Host "*********************************************"

    #Write-Host $ReportData
    #(Remove-SharedReferences -ReportFile $ReportFile)

    #Write-Host $ReportExecutionWarnings

    $ExecutionInfo = $ReportExecutionProxy.LoadReportDefinition($ReportData, [ref] $ReportExecutionWarnings);

    # loop through the report execution parameters
    foreach($Parameter in $ExecutionInfo.Parameters)
    {
        # create new item parameter object
        $ItemParameter = New-Object "$ReportServerProxyNamespace.ItemParameter";

        # fill in the properties except valid values, that one needs special processing
        Copy-ObjectProperties -SourceObject $Parameter -TargetObject $ItemParameter;

        # fill in the valid values
        $ItemParameter.ValidValues = Convert-ValidValues -SourceValidValues $Parameter.ValidValues;

        # add to list
        $ReportParameters += $ItemParameter;
    }

    # force the parameters to update
    Write-Host "Updating report parameters for $ReportFolder/$ReportName"
    if ($IsReportService2005) {
        $ReportServerProxy.SetReportParameters("$ReportFolder/$ReportName", $ReportParameters);
    }
    elseif ($IsReportService2010) {
        $ReportServerProxy.SetItemParameters("$ReportFolder/$ReportName", $ReportParameters);
    }
    else { Write-Warning 'Report Service Unknown in Update-ReportParameters method. Use ReportService2005 or ReportService2010.' }
}
```

Anyone knows how I could sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar problem but took a slightly different approach. Rather than using powershell and octopus directly I used the useful open source tool [RSBuild](https://rsbuild.codeplex.com/) to deploy the reports. It is pretty easy to bundle up the `rsbuild.exe` executable (it is tiny) and a `deploy.config` along with your reports inside the octopus package. Then you can use octopus's substitution feature to rewrite the config file and Powershell function to execute the executable. This also has the advantage that you can deploy easily without octopus, the config for data sources and reports is declarative in XML rather than procedural in Powershell and the smarts of your scripted deployment can live alongside your reports rather than buried in Octopus.

So my config looks a bit like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
    <Globals>
        <Global Name="CollapsedHeight">0.5in</Global>
    </Globals>
    <ReportServers>
        <ReportServer Name="RS1" Protocol="http" Host="${ReportServer}" Path="${ReportServerPath}" Timeout="30" />
    </ReportServers>
    <DataSources>
        <DataSource Name="Source1" Publish="true" Overwrite="true" TargetFolder="Data Sources" ReportServer="RS1">
            <ConnectionString>data source=${ReportServer};initial catalog=${DatabaseName}</ConnectionString>
            <CredentialRetrieval>Store</CredentialRetrieval>
            <WindowsCredentials>False</WindowsCredentials>
            <UserName>${RepotrUser}</UserName>
            <Password>${ReportsPassword}</Password>
        </DataSource>
    </DataSources>
    <Reports>
        <ReportGroup Name="Details" DataSourceName="Source1" TargetFolder="Reports"
            ReportServer="RS1" CacheTime="10080">
            <Report Name="BusinessReportABC">
                <FilePath>reports\BusinessReportABC.rdl</FilePath>
            </Report>
            <!--More reports here-->
        </ReportGroup>
    </Reports>
</Settings>
```

My deployed octopacked artefacts contain RSBuild.Core.dll, RSBuild.exe, deploy.config and the reports files

Then I simply call the executable using powershell:

```
PS> rsbuild deploy.config
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @alastairtree. This definitely looks like a good approach. I actually found an answer to my problem above. Was using the wrong ReportExecution Proxy Url as mentioned [here](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Library/issues/261). I guess using the Octopus Step Template is similar to using RSBuild.

Comment: Hi @alastairtree,  i am getting _[Settings]: Configuration system failed to initialize_ did have this problem when using RSBuild, also it seems like a dead projects...

Comment: @borik no I did not. Have you checked you are substituting all the ${XYZ} template variables in the example? Perhaps try just deploying one report? It may seem like a dead project but for me it just works, maybe it is not "dead", and more "done".

Comment: @alastairtree i used bare min config to test it out, and went trough documentation to check tags, etc..... seems like i am missing some kind of dependency...